# como carregar um select com dados vindos de uma API com AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Boa noite, não estou conseguindo carregar um select no angularJS! Ele nao carrega, fica em branco. Vou postar o codigo, se alguem puder me ajudar agradeço!!
**Controller:**

```
<script>
    angular.module("cadastroMedico", []);
    angular.module("cadastroMedico").controller("cadastroMedicoController", function ($scope, $http){
      $scope.app = "Cadastro de paciêntes";
      $scope.pacienteEspe = [
      ];

      var pacienteEspecial = function (){

      $http.get("http://localhost:27623/api/amb/Diseases/TESTES%20CUTANEOS%20DE%20LEITURA%20IMEDIATA").then(function (data) {
           $scope.pacienteEspe = data;
           console.log(data);
       }); 


      };

      pacienteEspecial();

    });
  </script>
```

index.html:

```
 <select class="form-control" ng-model="paciente.pacienteEspe" ng-options="pacienteEsp.Procedimento_tuss for pacienteEsp in pacienteEspe">
             <option value="">Selecione uma opcão</option>
           </select>
```

ele nao carrega, ele fica como se os dados estivessem lá, porem nao tem nada! ja tentei de tudo.. Se alguem puder ajudar..

Valeu!
[image: Aqui está como ele fica]

Retorno no console: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Poderia mostrar um exemplo de JSON retornado pela API?

Comment: [
  {
    "Id_amb92": 79,
    "Cod_amb92": "19010117",
    "Procedimento_amb92": "TESTES CUTANEOS DE LEITURA IMEDIATA",
    "Cod_tuss": "41401425",
    "Procedimento_tuss": "TESTES DE CONTATO - ATÉ 30 SUBSTÂNCIAS",
    "Ch": "60"
  }
]


Obs: quando exibo somete o array {{pacienteEspe }} ele me exibe exatamente isso! E algumas informações como resposta da API, no caso 200.

Comment: @leonardobarussi Tem como postar na sua pergunta como está o JSON recebido do server-side? Digo, ele sendo mostrado no console na aba network do navegador, ou até mesmo diretamente no navegador, chamando a URL.

Comment: `$scope.pacienteEspe = data.data;`

Comment: @jbueno deu certo! rapaaaaaaaaaz, foi quase 2 dias batendo cabeça com esse problema! Muito obrigado velho!

Comment: Beleza!! @jbueno voce poderia me explicar porque eu tive que repetir o data?

Comment: Sim, veja o `console.log`. Aquele é o retorno da função `get`, os dados retornados do server-side ficam na propriedade `data` deste retorno. Seria melhor você dar um nome mais descritivo, como `response` ou qqr outro equivalente. Entende? Este objeto representa a resposta inteira e não apenas os dados, os dados são parte da resposta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em uma análise inicial me parece que seu código não possui nenhum problema. O que pode estar acontecendo é que sua aplicação não está sendo inicializada corretamente.

Segue abaixo o seu código em estado funcional, com dados pré-carregados e uma *view* para iteração com o *controller*:

```js
angular.module("cadastroMedico", [])
    .controller("cadastroMedicoController", function($scope) {
        $scope.app = "Cadastro de pacientes";
        $scope.pacienteEspe = [
            {
                "Id_amb92": 79,
                "Cod_amb92": "19010117",
                "Procedimento_amb92": "TESTES CUTANEOS DE LEITURA IMEDIATA",
                "Cod_tuss": "41401425",
                "Procedimento_tuss": "TESTES DE CONTATO - ATÉ 30 SUBSTÂNCIAS",
                "Ch": "60"
            }
        ];
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="cadastroMedico">

  <div ng-controller="cadastroMedicoController">
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="paciente.pacienteEspe" ng-options="pacienteEsp.Procedimento_tuss for pacienteEsp in pacienteEspe">
     <option value="">Selecione uma opcão</option>
    </select>
    <pre>{{paciente | json}}</pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: então, ai é que está. Quando eu carrego o array manualmente como voce fez, sem a API jogando o JSON nela, o select carrega normalmente. O problema é quando eu carrego o select com os JSONS da API. Ele está me trazendo o valor corretamente, tanto que se eu exibir o que tem dentro do array quando carrego ele com a API {{ pacienteEspe }} ele me exibe exatamente o JSON que eu preciso, mas na hora de carregar no select ele me mostra a imagem que eu apresentei acima =/

Comment: Cara, com esse codigo que voce mandou formatado, aconteceu algumas mudanças. <pre>{{paciente | json}}</pre> com esse codigo, ele mostra quando eu clico, o JSON inteiro da API. Porem ainda não exibe no SELECT. Ele aparece em branco!

Comment: @leonardobarussi então seu select está provavelmente lendo do escopo errado. Para fins de teste, mude seu ng-options para "`pacienteEsp.Procedimento_tuss for pacienteEsp in $parent.pacienteEspe`". Isso pode acontecer se o conteúdo estiver dentro de um `ng-if`.

Comment: "pacienteEsp.Id_amb92 for pacienteEsp in $parent.pacienteEspe" com esse codigo ele nao funcionou. Agora ele nao exibe nada! Vou criar um novo projeto, colocar apenas um select e tentar. Dou noticias aqui caso de certo! Só um momento

Comment: Com esse ultimo codigo que voce informou ele nao pegou. Porem agora o SELECT aparece "undefined", seria alguma coisa que eu nao devini?

Comment: @leonardobarussi Ainda me parece uma questão de escopo. Você poderia postar mais do seu código aqui?

Comment: claro! fiz inline para testar. Vou postar aqui e voce da uma olhada!!

Comment: `<script>
    angular.module("cadastroMedico", []);
    angular.module("cadastroMedico").controller("cadastroMedicoController", function ($scope, $http){
        $scope.pacienteEspe = [

        ];

      var pacienteEspecial = function (){

      $http.get("http://localhost:27623/api/amb/listdiseases").then(function (data) {
           $scope.pacienteEspe = data;
           console.log(data);
       }); 
      

      };

      pacienteEspecial();

    });`

Comment: `<body ng-controller="cadastroMedicoController">

 <div>
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="paciente.pacienteEspe" ng-options="pacienteEspe.Id_amb92 for pacienteEsp in pacienteEspe">
     <option value="">Selecione uma opcão</option>
    </select>
    <pre>{{paciente | json}}</pre>
  </div>`

Comment: Não sei velho, o array está identico ao json vindo da API. E não funciona, não mudo NADA no select! Com o array ele me exibe, com a API não. Mostra um valor undefined!

Comment: Valeu a força!! Deu certo.

Comment: @leonardobarussi Fico feliz que tenha funcionado! Foi realmente um problema de escopo?